# Dual python versions and numpy issue

Tags: python, upgrade

I am newbie to Python.. so please excuse if my questions are too basic..
I want to install iris (a software for visualizing NWP data) which required Python2.7.*. I have Python2.6.6 on my RHEL-6 machine.
I have downloaded the Python 2.7.3 source and built it with a soft link as python273 instead of just python to access both the versions. I have followed the "make altinstall" process as mentioned in this forum.

I want to install numpy 1.6+ and scipy0.11. Now the problems are:
1. numpy is accessible by older version of python not python 2.7.3
2. scipy is not installing..

Kindly let me know where to start all over again and what installation logs would you be needing for troubleshooting?

Regards & Thanks in advance
Raghu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [NumPy](http://www.scipy.org/Download) and [intall it from source](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Linux). Take a look at [these](http://www.iram.fr/IRAMFR/GILDAS/doc/html/gildas-python-html/node38.html) instructions which explain how to install NumPy with the non-default Python.

Also, Python2.6 is needed by RHEL6 for stuff like `YUM`, but a normal user doesn't actually care if he/she is using Python2.6 or Python2.7 except for cases like yours. Since RHEL adopt new libraries and applications quite slow, I've had issues similar to yours.

If you don't want to provide this iris software to all your users, consider installing everything from source as a non-root user.